# How to remove the white circling box upon clicking in Firefox on Bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I have the following code:

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Help</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact/a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Right Aligned Navbar</h3>
    <p>some text.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Now if you execute the above code in Firefox and click on `About`. You'll see something like this:

[image]

How can I remove the white circling box?
On Safari or Chrome there is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Dotted borders around links are an accessibility feature most browsers
>   have by default. It's for users who must or choose to navigate by
>   keyboard, there is a visual style applied to those links when "tabbed"
>   to. These borders also show up when the link is clicked (in it's
>   "active" state), and can be an eyesore depending on the design
>   (especially when using something like CSS image replacement, the
>   borders span the length of the screen).

To remove do this:

**FIREFOX**

```
input::-moz-focus-inner { 
  border: 0; 
}
```

**FOR ALL**

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  outline:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the default Bootstrap CSS rule:

```
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

You need to set `outline: 0` on focus. If you want to remove it specifically on the navbar item, you can use the code in the snippet.

Otherwise, overwrite it for all the links with `a:focus { outline: 0 none; }` Check that the custom CSS priority order is higher i.e. placed after Bootstrap file.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}

/* Added code */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus { 
   outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Help</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact/a>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Right Aligned Navbar</h3>
    <p>some text.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```